# How do I access cPanel after default installation using VPS Control Panel

Tags: vps

So, I just bought my first VPS and chose the OS to be Centos + cPanel, using the VPS Control Panel.

The trouble is that I can't figure out the URL to get to cPanel afterwards.

I tried http://server.name:2086 and http://server.name/cpanel but with no luck. Any ideas?

PS: http://server.name correctly serves the Apache 2 Test Page.

Comment: Ask your provider, this is probably a FAQ.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH into the machine, and take a look at the 'netstat -anp' output.  WHM is probably running on a non-standard port.

If you can't connect even with the right port, contact your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Domain name should point to the server correct IP. But it would be better using the link like below:
http://192.168.1.1:2086 - for WHM access